# Zig / ziglings async => error: async has not been implemented in the self-hosted compiler yet

Tags: asynchronous, zig

So I am new to Zig and trying to learn it through Ziglings exercises.
I am trying to come across the `async` exercise, however in each correction of the exercise that I see, I am doing the exact same thing, however, here is what the compiler has to say:

```
xercises/084_async.zig:51:18: error: async has not been implemented in the self-hosted compiler yet
    _ = async foo();
        ~~~~~~~~~^~
referenced by:
    callMain: /snap/zig/8241/lib/std/start.zig:564:17
    initEventLoopAndCallMain: /snap/zig/8241/lib/std/start.zig:508:34
    remaining reference traces hidden; use '-freference-trace' to see all reference traces
```

And here is my code, minus the comments:

```
const print = @import("std").debug.print;

pub fn main() void {
    // Additional Hint: you can assign things to '_' when you
    // don't intend to do anything with them.
    _ = async foo();
}

fn foo() void {
    print("foo() A\n", .{});
    suspend {}
    print("foo() B\n", .{});
}
```

What is wrong with what I have done ?
Thanks.

Comment: Assuming you're using the latest 'stable' release 0.11, async code execution is [not featured](https://ziglang.org/news/0.11.0-postponed-again/). [Issue on github](https://github.com/ziglang/zig/issues/6025). I think it was part of an older release, then got removed due to technical difficulties. Likely, it won't be part of 0.12 either. There's also an [issue on the ziglings main repo](https://codeberg.org/ziglings/exercises/issues/36) btw.

Comment: The async functions in Ziglings are currently hidden. We hope to be able to integrate them again soon.

Answer (score 0):

AFAICT [ziglings](https://codeberg.org/ziglings/exercises/#getting-started) meant to be used with a [development](https://ziglang.org/download/) build of `zig` , not stable:
*From the ziglings/exercises repo linked above:*

> Install a development build of the Zig compiler. (See the "master" section of the downloads page.)
> Verify the installation and build number of zig like so:
>
> ```bash
> $ zig version
> 0.12.0-dev.xxxx+xxxxxxxxx
> ```

Note: I'm also new to zig, working through these myself and haven't gotten to async yet, but I could not get exercises to compile correctly on stable. (0.11.0 at time of writing)